# Keystore file not set for signing config release flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am new in flutter.And i have a question.I do apk file.I follow steps by official documentation.I use 
`'flutter build appbundle'` or `'flutter build apk'`. And i  have exception.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

Comment: [https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) Sections "Signing the app" and "Configure signing in gradle".